# Shortcut to Repeating the Last Action in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

There's a very cool shortcut in Illustrator: you press <kbd>Command/CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and Illustrator repeats the last action for you.

Is there a shortcut that does this or at least something similar in Photoshop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sort of....

The *closest* thing to this is `Edit > Transform > Again` --
 <kbd>Command/CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd> --- But this only works for transformations. And it only repeats the last transformation. Unlike Illustrator, it *won't* do things like repeat a copy *and* transform.

Comment: Repeat last is one of the single most useful things in maya that i wish theyd impolement in all adobe software.

Comment: The "Last Filter" shortcut also repeats, well, the last filter

Comment: Today is not the first time I've gotten Ai and Ps mixed up and Googled how to do this in Ps. D'oh! Despite not being able to use this for click-drag duplication, I just found a workaround by duplicating the layer in place, then using this shortcut to repeat the last-used move transformation.

Comment: @Mentalist in Adobe Photoshop CC the drag operation doesn't seem to register as a "transformation", so I cannot use Command-Shift-T to repeat it.  Can you add more detail?

Comment: @JonathanCross You are correct that drag duplication doesn't work. But if you don't mind doing it as a **Transform** operation (`Cmd` `T`) then you get the added benefit of being able to rotate, scale, etc too. Unfortunately it doesn't appear to work with Smart Objects though. You can **Duplicate Layer** and **Transform > Again** repeatedly. (`Shift` `Cmd` `T` is my shortcut to transform again, but can't remember if that's default or custom.)

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Alt-U worked for me repeating Hue/Saturation on another layer of the image in Photoshop 2023 in Windows

Comment: Adding the Alt key to adjustment shortcuts actually means "Open Adjustment with the last used settings". (works with levels, curves, h/s, cont/bright, etc) It may seem like a "repeat" but it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to repeat a 'filter' you can do it by pressing ctrl+f. It will repeat the most recent filter you used.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Actually, there is. Under Edit > Step and Repeat or CMD/CTRL + ALT + U.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not seeing that in my Photoshop menus.

Comment: Nor I; also the shortcut listed does nothing for me in a plain-jane install of PS CC 2019

Comment: Didn't work for me when I tested. I tried after duplicating and also after transforming.

Comment: This menu option doesn't exist on Mac Photoshop CC.